# Pra que serve a tag </datalist>?

Tags: html, html5, html-tags

Quando eu estava usando o Sublime Text para editar um arquivo `html`, percebi que ele me sugeriu uma tag com o nome de `datalist`.

Eu nunca tinha visto sobre essa tag antes, mas parece que [realmente existe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).

Como não vi nenhum explicação em português sobre o assunto, resolvi fazer essa pergunta aqui:

- Para que serve a tag `</datalist>`?
- Essa tag é nova?
- De alguma forma, ela pode substituir a funcionalidade de "autocomplemento" que existem atualmente em várias bibliotecas/frameworks em `Javascript`?

Comment: Desconhecia a tag, bacana demais @Wallace. +1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

O elemento datalist, novo no HTML 5, mostra uma lista de elementos predefinidos como opção para uma caixa de entrada de texto. Caso o browser não suporte este componente, ele pode exibir os elementos que compõem o datalist em forma de texto simples.

Dentro do elemento input, o atributo `list` faz referência ao elemento datalist através do seu id e cada elemento de um datalist é identificado pelo elemento option.

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Música</legend>
<label for="estilo"> Qual o seu estilo musical ?</label>
<input id="estilo" name="estilo" type="text" list="listaestilos"/>
<datalist id="listaestilos"><br/>Escolha entre estes:
<option value="samba">Samba</option>
<option value="blues">Blues</option>
<option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
<option value="mpb">MPB</option>
<option value="rock">Rock</option>
<option value="clássico">Clássico</option>
<option value="bossanova">Bossa-Nova</option>
<option value="pop">Pop</option>
</datalist>
</fieldset>
```

[Fonte:Fábio Flatschart Elemento datalist](http://flatschart.com/html5/datalist.html)

> Observação : No navegador Opera 11, este componente é renderizado perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo de um elemento datatalist pode ser exibido de maneira alternativa para outros browsers que não suportam este recurso através da inclusão de um elemento select.

```html
    <fieldset>
<legend>Música</legend>
<label for="estilo">Qual o seu estilo musical ? </label>
<input id="estilo" name="estilo" type="text" list="listaestilos">
<datalist id="listaestilos">
<label for="estiloalt" > Ou, selecione desta lista</label>
<select name="estiloalt" id="estiloalt">
<option value="samba">Samba</option>
<option value="blues">Blues</option>
<option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
<option value="mpb">MPB</option>
<option value="rock">Rock</option>
<option value="clássico">Clássico</option>
<option value="bossanova">Bossa-Nova</option>
<option value="pop">Pop</option>
</select>
   </datalist>
   </fieldset>
```

[Fonte:Fábio Flatschart Elemento datalist com conteúdo alternativo](http://flatschart.com/html5/datalist2.html)

No Safari o código acima é visto da seguinte forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse elemento não tem nenhum atributo a não ser os [Global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), comuns para todos os elementos.

---

### Comportamento Inusitado

> Até a presente data (17/07/2018) aqui na minha maquina - Windows 10,  Chrome Versão 67.0.3396.99 e Opera 54.0.2952.54 - se a lista de elementos predefinidos estiver aberta

[image: lista aberta]

> e rolar o scroll do navegador a lista permanece fixa na tela.

[image: tela rolada]

Answer (score 15):

> Para que serve a tag  <\datalist>?

É usada para fornecer um recurso de "preenchimento automático" em elementos do formulário. Ela permite que você forneça uma lista de opções predefinidas ao usuário à medida que eles inserem dados.

Por exemplo, se um usuário começar a inserir algum texto em um textcampo, uma lista seria suspensa com valores pré-preenchidos que eles poderiam escolher.

A tag `<datalist>` pode ser usada em conjunto com um `<input>` elemento que contém um `list` atributo.

Um exemplo de um elemento `<input>` com valores pré-definidos em um `<datalist>`:

```html
<form action="formulario_cor.php" method="post">
<label for="cor">Qual sua cor favorita? </label>
    <input list="cor" name="cor" >
    <datalist id="cor">
        <option value="Vermelho">
        <option value="Rosa">
        <option value="Amarelo">
        <option value="Verde">
        <option value="Azul">
        <option value="Preto">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

> Essa tag é nova?

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) da w3schools a tag `<datalist>` é nova em HTML5.

> De alguma forma, ela pode substituir a funcionalidade de
>   "autocomplemento" que existem atualmente em várias
>   bibliotecas/frameworks em Javascript?

Graças a tag Datalist não será mais necessário usar `jQuery` ou algum outro framework `JavaScript`, juntamente com algum código no lado do servidor para implementar a funcionalidade de autocomplemento nas entradas, procurar ou preencher dados em formulários, que comumente ele é acionado quando o usuário digita uma letra.

Se, por exemplo, tivemos uma entrada onde o usuário deve incluir seu país (como no exemplo a cima), podemos adicionar a lista por datalist elemento, que fornece ao usuários certas sugestões preenchidas ou limitada apenas aos países que são aceitos para registro.

Comment: Bom exemplo +1!

Comment: Obrigada! @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 10):

Como muitos já responderam, o `<datalist>` diferente do `<select>` normal tem uma caixa de texto, ou seja é possível filtrar os resultados de um combobox conforme o que digitar. Note que esta é uma tag que ainda não é 100% implementada ou os navegadores ainda possuem um ou outro BUG.

Conforme o https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist:

1. Opera e Chrome (Desktop):

   - Tem suporte parcial, mas quando a lista é muito longa alguns com que alguns itens não possam ser selecionados.
2. IE11 e Msedge:

   - Tem suporte parcial, mas no IE e Edge dispara os eventos de entrada de texto e `change` depois de selecionado um item.
3. Firefox

   - Tem suporte parcial, mas não suporta `<datalist>` com inputs que não sejam do tipo `text`, por exemplo `number`, `range` e `color`.
4. Não é suportado pelos navegadores:

   Safari para Mac OSX (pelo menos a até a versão 10.1 e Preview) e Safari para iOS
5. **É suportado** completamente pelos seguintes navegadores:

   Navegador nativo do Android 4.4.4 e Chrome 57 para Android

Então creio que ainda é algo a se pensar no uso, o link http://flatschart.com/html5/datalist.html apontou um bom exemplo de fallback para navegadores que não suportam em nada o datalist:

```html
<label for="estilo">Qual o seu estilo musical?</label>
<input id="estilo" name="estilo" type="text" list="listaestilos">
<datalist id="listaestilos">
    <label for="estiloalt"> Ou, selecione desta lista</label>
    <select name="estiloalt" id="estiloalt">
        <option value="samba">Samba</option>
        <option value="blues">Blues</option>
        <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
        <option value="mpb">MPB</option>
        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
        <option value="clássico">Clássico</option>
        <option value="bossanova">Bossa-Nova</option>
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
    </select>
</datalist>
```

Claro que não resolve os demais bugs, então no caso creio que seja algo bom para se evitar se desejar compatibilidade, mesmo sendo algo bom que resolverá o problema e ajudaria a não ter dependências ainda não é algo "100%"

---

### Alternativas

Apesar de não ser o foco da pergunta, pode ser de interesse buscar alternativas mesmo que com dependencias, uma que eu sugiro seriam os:

- http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ para quem usa jQuery
- https://select2.github.io para Bootstrap
- https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-autocomplete para quem usa Angular.js
- https://github.com/angular/material para quem usa Angular.js com Material (um tema para Angular.js)
- https://github.com/Pixabay/JavaScript-autoComplete para quem não usa nenhuma lib (VanillaJS)

Answer (score 7):

A tag  especifica uma lista de opções pré-definidas para um elemento .

A tag  é usada para fornecer um recurso de "preenchimento automático" em elementos . Os usuários verão uma lista suspensa de opções pré-definidas à medida que eles inserem dados.

Use o atributo de lista do elemento  para vinculá-lo juntamente com um elemento .

**Exemplo:**

```html
<input list="browsers">
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
```

**Elemento datalist**

O elemento datalist, novo no HTML 5, mostra uma lista de elementos predefinidos como opção para um caixa de entrada de texto. Caso o browser não suporte este componente, ele pode exibir os elementos que compõem o datalist em forma de texto simples.

Dentro do elemento input, o atributo ,list faz referência ao elemento datalist através do seu id e cada elemento de um datalist é identificado pelo elemento option.

Observação : No navegador Opera 11, este componente é renderizado perfeitamente.Veja no arquivo Elemento datalist com conteúdo alternativo a solução para navegadores que não ainda oferecem suporte à este elemento.

```html
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Música</legend>
     <label for="estilo"> Qual o seu estilo musical ?</label>
     <input id="estilo" name="estilo" type="text" list="listaestilos"/>
     <datalist id="listaestilos"><br/>Escolha entre estes:
       <option value="samba">Samba</option>
       <option value="blues">Blues</option>
       <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
       <option value="mpb">MPB</option>
       <option value="rock">Rock</option>
       <option value="clássico">Clássico</option>
       <option value="bossanova">Bossa-Nova</option>
       <option value="pop">Pop</option>
     </datalist>
    </fieldset>
```

<sub>Fonte: http://flatschart.com/html5/datalist.html</sub>

Comment: Ótimo exemplos +1, fiz uma edição que creio ser pertinente. Até mais.

Comment: Obrigado @Guilherme

Answer (score 4):

### O que precedeu a funcionalidade datalist?

> Um destaque entre os mais utilizados gadgets Javascript na década
>   anterior tem sido a caixa de conteúdo autocomplete gadget. Cada
>   estrutura de Javascript tem seu próprio gadget autocomplete particular
>   e um lote considerável deles tem chegado a ser verdadeiramente
>   louvável. Muito parecido com a primeira experiência do marcador de
>   posição com a marcação, uma utilidade utilizada de vez em quando foi
>   transferida de um utilitário Javascript apenas para HTML através do
>   novo componente DATALIST.

```
  <datalist></datalist>
```

### O que ela realmente é?

> O Elemento HTML  contém um conjunto de elementos 
>   que falam com as qualidades acessíveis para diferentes controles. A
>   tag  define um arranjo de escolhas predefinidas para um
>   componente de entrada. A tag  é utilizada para fornecer uma
>   oferta de "autocomplete" nos componentes de entrada. Os clientes verão
>   um arranjo drop-down de escolhas predefinidas como informações de
>   entrada. Você pode utilizar o cronograma do componente de entrada para
>   associá-lo a um componente datalist.

### Exemplos:

```
<datalist>

<option value="option value">

</datalist>
```

Exemplo 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
        <html>
     
    <head>
         <title>Title name will go here</title>
    </head>
     
    <body>
         
        <input list="country">
         
        <datalist id="country">
     
            <option value="India">
            <option value="Australia">
            <option value="Sourth Africa">
            <option value="Canada">
            <option value="America">
 
        </datalist>
         
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
         
    </body>
     
    </html>
```

### Conclusão:

> O que é fornecido é uma lista de preenchimento automático muito
>   rudimentar, mas útil, de itens existentes que correspondem ao texto
>   fornecido. Claro que a falta de estilo que vem com os elementos OPTION
>   não é ideal, e não há nenhum método para ligar DATALIST até um ponto de
>   extremidade de serviço para sugestões mais dinâmicas, mas este novo
>   elemento é um passo na direção certa!

### Referências

Os trechos citados foram traduzidos [daqui](http://www.html5andcss3.org/html5datalist.php) e [daqui](https://davidwalsh.name/datalist).

Comment: É interessante essa visão sobre o datalist mais aprofudada, por que usamos ela sem nem se ater a esses detalhes... eu inclusive só vim mesmo conhecer depois de pesquisar quando fui utilizar em um sistema.