# Como exibir o texto no datalist e não o seu valor?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-tags

Fiz um autocomplete acoplado em um campo `input` sem muita dificuldade, conforme mostra a seguir:

```html
<label>Professor</label>
<input type="text" list="list-professor" name="professor_id">
<datalist id="list-professor">
   <select>
      <option value="1">Roberto</option>
      <option value="2">Rosana</option>
      <option value="3">Romualdo</option>
   </select>
</datalist>
```

O `datalist` retorna sempre o valor contido no atributo `value`.

Gostaria de autocompletar o `input` tipo `text` com o Nome da Pessoa, mas não queria perder o `ID` ao enviar o formulário.

Pensei em tentar atribuir o valor dos `ID's` em um campo do tipo `hidden`, mas não sei como atribuir o valor quando houver seleção na `datalist`.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta logo abaixo, pelo que entendi você queria enviar o `id`e selecionar o nome do `Professor`

Comment: Erick eu fiz umas edições que creio ser pertinente, caso não seja me informe que volto como era antes, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre como funcionam as coisas por aqui.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela sua contribuição! Fiz a implementação conforme sua orientação e resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entendi que deseja enviar o `id` e o input exiba o nome do professor.

Fiz um pequena mudança no seu *HTML*, em `value` adicione os nomes dos *Professores*, e em `data-value` coloquei o `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var value = $('input').val();
        console.log($('#list-professor [value="' + value + '"]').data('value'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Professor</label>
<input type="text" list="list-professor" name="professor_id">
<datalist id="list-professor">
   <select>
      <option data-value="1" value="Roberto"></option>
      <option data-value="2" value="Rosana"></option>
      <option data-value="3" value="Romualdo"></option>
   </select>
</datalist>
<button>Enviar</button>
```

Recomendo a leitura:

- [Pra que serve a tag `</datalist>`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist/197573)

Comment: Marconi, a solução que você apresentou resolveu meu problema perfeitamente. Fiz uma pequena alteração no seu código onde alterei o evento para _'focusout'_ no próprio _'input'_ tipo _'text'_ que altera o _'value'_ de um _'input'_ tipo _'hidden'_ com o _'data-value'_.