# Existe algum evento específico no Javascript para detectar quando um <option> de um <datalist> é selecionado?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-option

No Javascript, é possível, através do `onchange`, `oninput` e afins, detectar se um determinado `input` é alterado.

Exemplo:

```js
var qs = function (el) { return document.querySelector(el); }


qs("#input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
     console.log('evento "input" %s', e.target.value);
});

qs("#input").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
     console.log('evento "change" %s', e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Através da tag [`<datalist>`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist) é possível também sugerir preenchimentos para um `input`. Também é possível detectar essa mudanças no input, já que a seleção de um item de um `datalist` preenche o input alvo.

Exemplo:

```js
var qs = function (el) { return document.querySelector(el); }


qs("#input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
     console.log('evento "input" %s', e.target.value);
});

qs("#input").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
     console.log('evento "change" %s', e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" list="datalist"/>

<datalist id="datalist">
 <option>Bola</option>
 <option>Peão</option>
 <option>Pipa</option>
</datalist>
```

Porém, no meu cenário, surgiu a seguinte necessidade: Ao invés de detectar as mudanças do `input`, preciso saber especificamente, através de um evento, quando uma `option` desse `datalist` é selecionada.

Tentei utilizar `onclick` e `mousedown` na tag `option` que está nesse `datalist`, porém sem sucesso.

Eu preciso exatamente disso, não de detectar as mudanças, mas sim de saber se o option foi selecionado ou não.

Existe alguma solução pronta para isso no Javascript?

<sub>**Observação**: O segundo exemplo que dei não resolve meu problema, pois o evento detecta as mudanças no `input`, e não se o `datalist > option` foi selecionado.</sub>

Comment: Acho que o evento `onselect` é o necessário pra solucionar o seu caso.

Comment: @mutlei Esse evento é para detectar seleção de texto, e não a escolha de uma opção de uma `datalist`. O que eu quero é diferente.

Comment: Tenta o evento `change` no datalist

Comment: Bom dia amigo! Quando ocorre o evento `change`, não significa que um `option` foi selecionado? Não consegui pegar bem o que deseja.

Comment: Já entendi o contexto. rs

Comment: @dvd não, pois na verdade você poderia digitar um valor que não está no `option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que não exista

Eu diria que tem que verificar com `querySelectorAll` para checar todos options

---

### Evento change

```js
function qs(query, context) {
   return (context || document).querySelector(query);
}

function qsa(query, context) {
   return (context || document).querySelectorAll(query);
}

qs("#input").addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    var options = qsa('#' + e.target.getAttribute('list') + ' > option'),
        values = [];
    
    [].forEach.call(options, function (option) {
        values.push(option.value)
    });

    var currentValue = e.target.value;

    if (values.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) {
         console.log('evento "change" %s', currentValue);
    }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" list="datalist"/>

<datalist id="datalist">
 <option>Bola</option>
 <option>Peão</option>
 <option>Pipa</option>
</datalist>
```

---

### Evento input

```js
function qs(query, context) {
   return (context || document).querySelector(query);
}
function qsa(query, context) {
   return (context || document).querySelectorAll(query);
}
  
var timerDataList = {};//Para usar com multiplos datalist

qs("#input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
     var listAttr = e.target.getAttribute('list');
     
     if (timerDataList[listAttr]) clearTimeout(timerDataList[listAttr]);
  
     timerDataList[listAttr] = setTimeout(executeCheckin, 100, e.target, listAttr);
});
  
function executeCheckin(target, listAttr) {
    var options = qsa( 'option', qs('#' + listAttr) ),
        values = [];
    
    [].forEach.call(options, function (option) {
        values.push(option.value)
    });
    var currentValue = target.value;
    if (values.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) {
         console.log('evento "input" %s', currentValue);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" list="datalist"/>

<datalist id="datalist">
 <option>Bola</option>
 <option>Peão</option>
 <option>Pipa</option>
</datalist>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um evento que faça o que pede, mas nada impede a criação de um.
Segue uma proposta.

```js
(function () {
  var event = new Event("selected")
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[list]")
  var onInput = function (evt) {
    var index = this.options.indexOf(this.input.value.toUpperCase())
    if (index != this.input.selectedIndex) {
      this.input.selectedIndex = index
      this.input.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
  };
  [].forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
    input.selectedIndex = -1
    var wrapper = {
      input: input,
      options: [].map.call(input.list.options, function (option) {
        return option.textContent.toUpperCase()
      })
    }
    input.addEventListener('input', onInput.bind(wrapper))
  })  
})()

input.addEventListener("selected", function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.selectedIndex)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" list="datalist"/>

<datalist id="datalist">
 <option>Bola</option>
 <option>Peão</option>
 <option>Pipa</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma, usando `.map`. Irá criar um array onde você verifica se o valor do `input` existe na array com `indexOf`. O exemplo abaixo é case sensitive; se digitar "pipa" não vai encontrar "Pipa". Mas se quiser, isso pode ser facilmente ajustado. Também fará diferença com palavras acentuadas.

```js
var qs = function (el) { return document.querySelector(el); }

qs("#input").addEventListener('change', function (e) {

   var datalist = document.body.querySelectorAll("#datalist option");
   var opt = [].map.call(datalist, function(o){
      return o.textContent
   });
   
   var optSel = ~opt.indexOf(e.target.value) ? true : false;
   
   // se optSel for true, significa que o valor existe no datalist
   console.log(optSel);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" list="datalist"/>

<datalist id="datalist">
 <option>Bola</option>
 <option>Peão</option>
 <option>Pipa</option>
</datalist>
```