# HTML5, usar <input> numa <select> para digitar uma das <option>

Tags: html5, css3

tudo bom? Seguinte, eu tenho uma select dentro de um html, veja:

```html
 <select>
  <option selected="selected" value>...</option>
  <option>opção 1</option>
  <option>opção 2</option>
 </select>
```

Eu tentei usar um input para digitar, ao invés de selecionar a option clicando.
Mas o input fica de lado, como se não fizesse parte da select

Minha dúvida é; realmente é possível fazer isto, digitar para selecionar as option, invés de selecionar clicando?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Saiba mais sobre datalist https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist/197573#197573

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo já até inclui o link na resposta! Bem completo o material lá!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Valeu! eu realmente não achei, porque estava pesquisando de um jeito errado. Ainda bem que você e o Hugo me ajudaram. Abraços

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara não sei se vai servir exatamente para vc, mas as vezes o `<datalist>` te atende.

Link sobre a tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

A diferença entre um `<select>` e um `<datalist>` é que no `select` vc determina as opções que o usuário é "obrigado" a escolher entre elas. Já o `datalist` vc oferece algumas sugestões para o usuário, mas ele é livre para digitar o que quiser, ou seja, é uma lista *pre-definida*, não uma lista *pre-determinada* como a `select`.

> The `<datalist>` element represents the list that represent predefined
>   options for other controls.

Traduzindo: *O elemento `<datalist>` representa a lista que representa opções predefinidas para outros controles.*

Fonte oficial W3C: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/datalist

**Dica:** Apesar de não ser o foco dessa pergunta aqui tem outra Pergunta que foi feita aqui no Stackoverflow e que tem mais informações sobre essas duas tags: [Pra que serve a tag </datalist>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist)

**Veja o exemplo da `datalist` funcionando.**

```html
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: exatamente o que eu precisava mano! Eu sou iniciante ainda, eu estava o dia inteiro tentando pesquisar como colocar um input dentro de uma select, mas nao sabia que existia uma tag que fazia o que eu precisava... muito obrigado pelos links e pela resposta, pode ter certeza que eu vou estudar muito.

Comment: @MSHijo isso meu jovem! Estudo! Principalmente as fontes oficiais, mesmo parecendo ser um texto mais chato, com certeza é o texto mais certo! Mas a principal linguagem que vc tem que aprender é o inglês, não se esqueça dela, pois infelizmente 90% do conteúdo em PT é copiado do Inglês e cheio de "lacunas". Então leia e tire sempre suas próprias conclusões. Sucesso! []´s

Comment: @MSHijo essa resposta tem mais umas informações sobre o Datalist que podem te ajudar a entender o funcionamento da tag e a diferença para a Select https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist

Comment: Sofri muito já com autocomplete num `input`... Nem conhecia essa tal `datalist`. ;O

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Em algumas situações é bem útil e fácil de implementar :D

Comment: Justamente. Quando precisei, fiz um "webservice" que retornasse um JSON, daí uma requisição ajax retornava esse JSON e por fim jogava no .autocomplete do jQuery-UI. Mó mão de obra comparado a esse datalist ser populado direto na renderização da página. kk