# Variável PHP no JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

O método simples e prático que encontrei aqui no Stack de passar uma variável PHP para uma JS funcionou bem até agora. Porém, com um certo conteúdo funciona apenas se eu alimentar essa variável PHP, mas deixar essa variável receber esse conteúdo através de uma query, não. (OBS: O set result completo da query tem 13.700 caracteres)

```
<?PHP 
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT MODELO FROM celular_banco");
    while($resultado=mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        $fracasso .= $resultado["MODELO"].',';
    }
  echo $fracasso; // LGA270.AVIVBK,LGA270.ACLRBK,
  $sucesso = "LGA270.AVIVBK,LGA270.ACLRBK,";
```

?>

```
<script>
var duvida = '<?PHP $sucesso;?>';
document.write(duvida); // OK!
</script>
FUNCIONA

<script>
var duvida = '<?PHP $fracasso;?>';
document.write(duvida); // SEM RESULTADO!
</script>
Não FUNCIONA
```

Comment: Tente isso no `PHP`: `echo (string) $fracasso;`

Comment: As variáveis duvida nos dois scripts serão var duvida = ''; Tem que ser <?PHP echo $sucesso;?> e <?PHP echo $fracasso;?> Ou `<?= $sucesso;?>` e `<?= $fracasso;?>`

Comment: Precisamos do echo senão o JS não entende. Ou eu não entendi sua ajuda...

Comment: Camarada. Infelizmente não funcionou com o (string)

Comment: Por quê exatamente você precisa passar esse conteúdo para o JS, para ele escrever no documento? Simplesmente não faz sentido isso e, se viu algo assim aqui no site, seria legal informar, pois tem coisa muito errada aí.

Comment: Anderson, Vamos lá: Primeiro peguei o script de autocomplete no W3schools. Nesse script o JS tem uma array com os itens já pré-definidos (países). Aqui eu estou precisando colocar um conteúdo provindo de uma query do php. Por isso eu estou tentando passar a variavel PHP para JS. Já fiz isso diversas vezes com barcode e outros mas agora não sei porque raios não funciona... Consigo até passar outros valores de uma consulta simples. Mas quando tento passar o resultado dessa While não dá certo. Estou muito desconfiado que o problema é essa While. Mas não sei o que esta bloqueando.

Comment: O que vi aqui no Stack e ja fiz muito e deu muito certo até o momento foi o esquema de conversão PHP>JS. Postei o código na própria pergunta (A variável $sucesso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu PHP entrega o próprio HTML ao cliente, o JavaScript nem precisa entrar na história. Isso que tentou fazer, mesmo que tenha visto no W3Scholls ou aqui mesmo no site, é gambiarra.

O que você pode fazer é entregar o HTML pronto. Algo como:

```
<input list="modelos" />
<datalist id="modelos">
<?php
  $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT MODELO FROM celular_banco");

  while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
  {
    echo "<option value='{$resultado['MODELO']}'/>";
  }
?>
</datalist>
```

Isso gerará para o cliente um HTML do tipo:

```html
<input list="modelos" />
<datalist id="modelos">
  <option value="Foo"/>
  <option value="Bar"/>
  <option value="Baz"/>
  <option value="Acme"/>
  <option value="Zing"/>
</datalist>
```

Que possui a propriedade de sugestão conforme o usuário digita.

[Pra que serve a tag </datalist>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197571/5878)

Outra opção que você tem é alimentar sua sugestão no formulário de forma assíncrona, via requisição AJAX, mas se você já entrega o HTML pronto com o PHP, não há necessidade de mais uma requisição.

Comment: Anderson!! E-s-p-e-t-a-c-u-l-a-r cara. Você OBLITEROU minha dúvida. Essa tag Datalist é tudo que eu precisava. SUCESSO INFINITO PRA VOCÊ MEU CHARÁ!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que a variável `$fracasso` só existe dentro do `while`, tente:

```
<?PHP
    var $fracasso = '';
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT MODELO FROM celular_banco");
    while($resultado=mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        $fracasso .= $resultado["MODELO"].',';
    }
    // Não entendi a necessidade das linhas abaixo... 
    echo $fracasso; // LGA270.AVIVBK,LGA270.ACLRBK,
    $sucesso = "LGA270.AVIVBK,LGA270.ACLRBK,";
   ?>
```

**JS (Havia faltado a parte do JS, deve ser adicionado o `echo` para funcionar corretamente)**

```
<script>
var duvida = '<?PHP echo $sucesso;?>';
document.write(duvida);

var duvida = '<?PHP echo $fracasso;?>';
document.write(duvida);
</script>
```

Comment: Celso, postei as linhas abaixo somente para mostrar que no PHP qualquer uma ecoam normalmente, Mas somente a $sucesso é recebida pela JS. To ficando maluco ja com isso...

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var duvida = '<?PHP $sucesso;?>';
    document.write(duvida); 
    var duvida = '<?PHP $fracasso;?>';
    document.write(duvida);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Leandro, Dentro da função, a página não traz resultado nem com um texto simples.